# Trying to loop through click event and make the div´s with it´s texts visible. Does somebody what the mistake is?

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is the html container:

```
      <div class="arrow-1">
        <div class="text-event">
          <p class="text-style-11">Text 1
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow">
          <div class="diamond">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="arrow-2">
        <div class="text-event">
          <p class="text-style-11">Text 2
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow">
          <div class="diamond">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="arrow-3">
        <div class="text-event">
          <p class="text-style-11">Text 3
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow">
          <div class="diamond">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="arrow-4">
        <div class="text-event">
          <p class="text-style-11"> Text 4
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow">
          <div class="diamond">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="arrow-5">
        <div class="text-event">
          <p class="text-style-11"> Text 5
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow">
          <div class="diamond">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

The paragraphs should be "visible" when text-event class clicked. Text style class is "hidden" by default. I did that already with other div boxes and it worked. Is there a 'p' declaration missing in the loop function? There is not even a console feedback when I pass the textEvent variable to the console.

```
const textEvent = document.querySelectorAll('.text-event');

for (var j = 0; j < textEvent.length; j++) (function (j) {
    textEvent[j].addEventListener('click', onclick);

    textEvent[j].onclick = function (ctrls) {
        ctrls.forEach(ctrl => {
            /* ctrl.getElementsByClassName('p')[0].innerHTML; */
            ctrl.document.getElementsByClassName('text-style-11').style.visibility = "visible";
        })
    }

})(j);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this code it should work fine:

```
const textEvent = document.querySelectorAll('.text-event');
   
  for (var j = 0; j < textEvent.length; j++)  {
    
            textEvent[j].addEventListener('click', (el) => {
                const clickedElement = el.currentTarget;    
                const innerParagraph = clickedElement.querySelector('.text-style-11');    
                innerParagraph.style.visibility = 'visible';
            });
  }
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array so you can't change the style property like that. The for loop strategy proposed by the OP and reiterated here is convoluted and even more obscure in the original question where it addressed the ctrls variable out of nowhere

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand very well your code but this is how I would do it.

1. First get all the element with class "text-event"
2. loop over that array and add an event listener to each of them.
3. When you click in one of them select the element with the class of text-style-11
4. To something to that element.

```
const textContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".text-event");

textContainers.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const textElement = element.querySelector(".text-style-11");
        textElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
});
```

Instead of adding styles directly, I recommend you to create a class and use classList toggle to add and remove that class.

```
    textContainers.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const textElement = element.querySelector(".text-style-11");
        textElement.classList.toggle("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Maxcode- toggle worked as well!

Answer (score 0):

You've already got a valid answer.. by the way here's the live snippet using the proper strategy to add an event listener to all your .text-event elements that will hide the inner paragraph embedded in the clicked box:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.text-event').forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const clickedElement = event.currentTarget;    
    const innerParagraph = clickedElement.querySelector('.text-style-11');    
    innerParagraph.style.visibility = 'visible';
  });
});
```

```css
.text-event {
  border: dotted gray 3px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-style-11{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-1">
  <div class="text-event">
    <p class="text-style-11">Alle Personen, die nicht sozialversicherungspflichtig beschäftigt sind (Beamte, Selbstständige, etc.)
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <div class="diamond">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="arrow-2">
  <div class="text-event">
    <p class="text-style-11">Einmalige Wartezeit 1 Monate
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <div class="diamond">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="arrow-3">
  <div class="text-event">
    <p class="text-style-11">Keine Karenzzeit
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <div class="diamond">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="arrow-4">
  <div class="text-event">
    <p class="text-style-11">Versichert sind nur Erstdiagnosen während der Versicherungslaufzeit (Herzinfarkt, Schlaganfall, Krebs, Blindheit oder Taubheit)
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <div class="diamond">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="arrow-5">
  <div class="text-event">
    <p class="text-style-11">Übernahme des noch ausstehenden Restsaldos von bis zu 135.000 €
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <div class="diamond">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you diegod! That was the solution. There was a little mistake on the css classes too.

Comment: Although there is no way getting an event with no css information attached to it. :))

Comment: you are using the word `event` in a weird way. The event is something occurring.. while the elements you marked with the `text-event` class are just elements. You are actually adding an event listener (hence the name: listening for an event to occur) to elements having a given characteristic (the css class) that you use to select them. By the way I wish to stress the fact that the first solution was given by someone else and I hope you'll accept that one.